# Making equal instance of Union without Union

Tags: union, sqlplus, database

These days, I've learned about DBMS. And now, I have trouble with using *sqlplus*.
The problem is I want these two table to be united without 'Union query'.

```
Table1 = '1','2','3','4','5'
Table2 = '1','2','6','7'
```

The Union result of these two tables is  `'1','2','3','4','5','6','7'`

But I want to achieve the same result without using `Union` by only using create, select, or insert.

Please, I really want to know alternative resolution of `Union`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically, you can try

```
insert
  into table1 ( col )
       select col
         from table2 t2
        where not exists (
                 select 1
                   from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.col = t2.col
              )
     ;
```

but i doubt that this will be much more efficient than a union in the first place.
similar comment holds for a construct like `insert into table1 select col from table2 minus select col from table 1`.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness. It works! Thx so much. If you have a chance to visit my county, I'll give you some food for your help.